# How to calculate birthday problem for collisions of a random number generator

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, random, birthday

I'm creating a script that generates random numbers for invoices as fully described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233676/randomly-generating-invoice-ids).

The [current version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244508/randomly-generating-invoice-ids) of my script includes logic to prevent collisions, but this means that every time there is a collision, the script has to generate a new number. If the script is running into collisions and regenerating too often, this will be a problem, so I need to figure out how often I can expect a given keyspace to generate collisions, such as the figures calculated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table).

For example, given a key space of 100000 for 5 digits (00000-99999), what percentage of collisions can I expect?

What's the formula to work this out, and how can I apply it (my maths skills are very limited)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork My maths is too weak for me to even begin to know how to approach this problem. Think high-school level.

Comment: Do you want an answer relative to your particular algorithm ? As opposed to the naive algorithm without the collision-sometimes-avoiding logic ? Perhaps you want to know the probability that your collision preventing logic will be forced to take action ? Is that logic perfectly reliable, or does it only avoid collisions with high probability ?

Comment: @Simon The logic of the script I use checks a database, and if a number is already in the database, it detects a new one. I'm trying to work out how often I can expect the script to come across something already in the database. If it's colliding on every other attempt then that would be a problem. I assume this is the naive algorithm. The idea of the script's logic is that it pre-empts any collisions and so, if it's working as it should, it will avoid actual collisions (or adding them to the database) 100% of the time.

Comment: `Perhaps you want to know the probability that your collision preventing logic will be forced to take action?` Yes, exactly this, and I think it's safe to assume the script's logic is perfectly reliable. If it isn't, there are bugs in it, and that will have to be addressed separately. To my eyes, it seems robust.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on those points. So before the collision preventing logic has a chance to do its work, are the numbers generated uniformly at (pseudo-)random from the set of possible numbers ? If so, then it is indeed the classic Birthday problem, and the answer to your question is given on the Wikipedia page to which you link.

Comment: Isn't it a dynamic question? So if you have $N$ possible invoice numbers, the first will be given without a collision, the second will be given without a collision with probability $p(1)=1-\tfrac{1}{N}$ and after $n$ invoices, the probability that a new one will be given without a collision is $p(n)=1-\tfrac{n}{N}$. Hence, with time, the probability of collision increases, and the number of randomizations needed to find a new number will also increase (geometrical distribution w.p. $p(n)$).

Comment: @Simon Could you point out to me which section/formula on the Wikipedia page you're referring to?

Comment: @YJT That's true, but it makes the sum overly complicated and the probability with the initial, full keyspace is fine for my needs, since I don't expect to approach even half of 99999 anytime soon, if ever. My business is too localised and niche for that.

Comment: In that case, why don't you simplify it? Let's say if $p=0.1$ is a reasonable collision chance for you. Set the key range to be 10 times larger than what you expect to sell in a reasonable amount of time. You will have a much better collision rate than 0.1 in the beginning and only towards the end (when you retire? :D ), you'll start colliding at the bad 10% rate.

Comment: @Prometheus, my apologies - I spoke too soon about the birthday problem. I agree with both of YJT's comments, since you deal with the collisions as they arise. If instead you chose to generate a bunch of keys, and THEN check those for collisions, then the probability that at least one collision was found would be addressed by the Birthday problem.

Comment: @YJT I want to keep the keyspace as low as possible, which is why I mentioned 5 digits and keyspace of 100,000, so an ability to work out what probabilities I can expect for a given keyspace would help me determine how low I can go without having my script running into collisions most of the time.

Comment: @Simon Are you saying that the birthday problem cannot be applied to calculate the initial probability of collisions for the 100,000 numbers between 000000 and 999999?

Comment: @Prometheus. We have (always) to define precisely the experiment, and the event in that experiment whose probability we want to know. Will you generate $N$ invoice numbers from that range, and then check your set of numbers for collisions, and ask what is the probability that you find at least one collision ? Or will you generate $N$ invoice numbers one at a time, checking each time whether you have a collision with a previously generated (and accepted) invoice number ? In the latter case, as YJT says, the probability changes according to how many invoice numbers you've already accepted.

Comment: @Simon It will be the latter, but as already stated several times now, I do not need to recalculate the probability after every single number generated. It's sufficient for me to know the *initial* probability of getting a collision from those 100,000 possible numbers, and to know that the probability will rise with time. I refuse to believe there's really no middle ground between the crude estimations of "10 times larger than you would expect" and recalculating the probability after single number that's generated.

Comment: @Prometheus, please read carefully the comments of YJT and the answer of Henry below. We are not being obtuse. I genuinely think you are failing to grasp the issue. The "initial probability of collision" is zero. Example: I generate the number 326,452. There is no collision, because there is only one number. My one customer has a unique invoice number. Another possible intepretation of "initial probability of collision" is that the second customer's number collides with the first. This is covered by YJT and Henry. It has probability 1/10^5.

Comment: Okay, I see where you're coming from now and my mistake in misunderstanding what I was asking for, sorry about that. Essentially then I don't know exactly what I want here, except that I want to get the equivalent of the probabilities in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), with number of hashes replaced by the number of numbers between 00000 and 99999 (100,000) and where the answer is a probability of the amount of collisions when generating those numbers. I suppose then it's a question of how those probabilities were calculated. Or would that not apply to my use case?

Comment: There is an alternative technique in which you start with some pool of numbers, say $0$ to $99999,$ randomly generate an integer $n$ in the range $0$ to $99999,$ and then pick the $(n+1)$st integer from your list, which at this point happens to be $n$. But the next time you generate $n$ in the range $0$ to $99998$ and then pick the $(n+1)$st number from the ones that have not yet been picked. The third time, $n$ is generated in the range $0$ to $99997.$ In general, if you have already generated $K$ invoice numbers, choose $n$ randomly from the range $0$ to $99999 - K.$

Comment: In the alternative technique you have the question of how to keep track of the remaining invoice numbers not yet used, but that's more a programming question than a math question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to intepret your question in the following precise way, which might not be what you intended, but is my best guess at what you meant:

Numbers will be chosen uniformly at random, one at a time, from a set of $n$ possible numbers (say the positive integers from $0$ to $n-1$ inclusive). At each step, if the number drawn has already been drawn, then it will be discarded. Otherwise, it will be added to a list of useable customer invoice numbers. This process will repeat until we have $m$ numbers (which will of course all be distinct from each other) in our list of invoice numbers. The idea being that our business has $m$ customers needing invoice numbers.

Let $Y$ be the total number of times we have to generate a number, until we have managed to get $m$ distinct ones. Then $Y$ is a random variable, taking values between $m$ and $\infty$ inclusive. We would like to know the expected value of $Y$, that is, what the "long-run average" value of $Y$ would be, if we were to repeat the whole experiment many times.

This is an instance of the "Coupon collector's problem". It can be shown (see for example pg. 216 of the paper "Birthday paradox, coupon collectors, caching algorithms and self-organising search" by Flajolet, Gardier and Thimonier in Discrete Applied Mathematics 39 (1992), pp. 207-229) that the expected value of $Y$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
E(Y)=n(H_n - H_{n-m}),
\end{equation}
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number:
\begin{equation}
H_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n},
\end{equation}
which Henry mentioned in his answer.

We can rewrite equation (1) as
\begin{equation}
E(Y)=n \left (\frac{1}{n-m+1} + \frac{1}{n-m+2} + \frac{1}{n-m+3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right ),
\end{equation}
but for a cheeky application of Wolfram Alpha, it's probably easier to use (1) as is. For example, let's suppose your keyspace has size one million ($n=10^6$) and that you have three and a half thousand customers ($m=3,500$). Then the expected number of calls to the random number generator is
\begin{equation}
E(Y)=10^6(H_{10^6}-H_{10^6 - 3500}).
\end{equation}
Wolfram Alpha says that this is about $3506$:
[Wolfram Alpha computation 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000%28HarmonicNumber%5B1000000%5D-HarmonicNumber%5B1000000-3500%5D%29).
You can use that link to play with the parameters $n$ and $m$. If you fix $m$ and increase $n$, you should see the expected number of calls decreases (as one would hope).

Bear in mind that the number of *collisions* is $Y-m$. However, the expected value of $Y-m$ is the same as the expected value of $Y$, minus $m$:
\begin{equation}
E(Y-m)=E(Y)-E(m)=E(Y)-m=n(H_n - H_{n-m})-m.
\end{equation}
Therefore in the example above, you would expect to have only about $3506-3500=6$ collisions on average.

You could do an experiment in code, to carry out many trials of the process, so that you could make a graph of average number of numbers drawn in the first $k$ trials, for $k$ between $1$ and $5000000$, say. You'd find that the points jumped around a lot, but eventually began to converge to the value of E(Y) predicted by the formula. This is an example of the "Law of Large Numbers". It gives an intuition for the meaning of the "expected value of a random variable".

**EDIT:**

In response to your recent comment above, thank you, and no problem ! It's a back-and-forth until we figure out what's what.

About that table, it looks to me as if the entries are given by the formula they give for $n(p;H)$, rounded to the nearest "nice" number. I found that out by trying a few on Wolfram Alpha. For example, [Wolfram Alpha computation 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%282*2%5E32*Log%5B1%2F%281-0.5%29%5D%29) gives about 77162.7, which appears in their table as 77000 (second row, second from last column). As I understand, the meaning of these numbers is: The least number of times you must generate a random number, before the probability that you have at least one collision is at least a certain amount. So if you generate 77162 random numbers uniformly from among 2^32 possible ones, then the probability that you'll have a collision is less than 50%, but if you generate 77163, then the probability that you'll have a collision is at least 50%. Note that this formula is only an approximation. The true threshold may not be exactly 77163, which is probably why they feel free to round it quite a lot, to 77000.

It sounds as if maybe you want to know how big the keyspace should be so that the probability of *no* collision is *more* than a certain value. That is, with probability at least such-and-such, you generate the $m$ invoice numbers you need, without any collisions. If so, then by rearranging their formula (and using the variable names I used above instead of theirs), we have
\begin{equation}
n \approx \frac{m^2}{2 \log \left ( \frac{1}{p} \right )}.
\end{equation}
They have used an approximation to $\log$ to get a simpler formula lower down the page, so let's do the same:
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
n \approx \frac{m^2}{2(1-p)}.
\end{equation}
Replacing $\log \left ( \frac{1}{p} \right )$ by $1-p$ is a reasonable approximation when $p$ is close to $1$ (which it will be in your application, if you want a high probability of no collisions). See the first plot here: [Wolfram Alpha computation 3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BLog%5B1%2Fp%5D%2C1-p%7D%2C%7Bp%2C0.01%2C1%7D%5D).

For example: You need $m=3500$ distinct random invoice numbers. You will choose them one at a time, uniformly at random, independently of each other, from a keyspace of size $n$. You want the probability of experiencing *no* collisions to be at least 99%. What's the smallest keyspace size $n$ that you can get away with ? It is approximately
\begin{equation}
\frac{3500^2}{2(1-0.99)} \approx 600000000,
\end{equation}
see here: [Wolfram Alpha computation 4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3500%5E2%2F%282*%281-0.99%29%29).

**SECOND EDIT:**

I have just checked the derivation of the approximation they use, and I found out that it gives an *upper bound* on the probability of no collisions. Therefore I am wrong to use the approximation to give *lower bounds* on that probability. However, the upper bound should be fairly close to the real value, provided $m$ is much less than $n$, so perhaps the above formula will still give you a useful rule of thumb. The exact value for the probability of no collisions is:
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} \left ( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right ) = \frac{1}{n^{m-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-m)!}.
\end{equation}
Indeed, if we plug that into Wolfram Alpha, using the $n=600000000$ calculated previously, and $m=3500$ as before, then we find that the probability of no collisions is about 98.98%, which is less than the 99% we'd hoped for: [Wolfram Alpha computation 5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1-k%2F600000000%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C3500-1%7D%5D) But it's pretty close, isn't it ?! If you wanted to insist on passing the 99% threshold, then you could just try larger values of $n$ one by one until you got what you needed. Perhaps you could use an interval bisection scheme, i.e. if you go too far, come half way back, etc. etc.

**THIRD EDIT:**

If instead of rounding the upper bound given by [Wolfram Alpha computation 4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3500%5E2%2F%282*%281-0.99%29%29) down to $600000000$, we used the actual upper bound, $612500000$, then it turns out to be enough to make the true value of the probability exceed 99%: [Wolfram Alpha computation 6](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1-k%2F612500000%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C3500-1%7D%5D).

**FOURTH EDIT:**

To clarify, the formula (3) (you can use the left-hand side or the right-hand side, whichever is easier for you) will give you the exact probability of no collisions. You could use it to make a table of probabilities corresponding to different values of $n$, and then choose the smallest value of $n$ such that the probability was greater than 99% (or whatever you like).

To know what rough range of values of $n$ you should include in your table, you can start with the right-hand side of formula (2), and go up or down from that value of $n$, as needed. You should beware - the right-hand side of (2) MIGHT sometimes be quite far from the true threshold value of $n$ that you want. I fell into that trap myself - a mistake that I corrected in my "Second Edit". The problem there is like this: Suppose I'm trying to work out how old you are, and I know that your friend is older than you, and that he is less than $56$ years old. If your age is $x$ and his age is $y$ then I have $x < y < 56$, from which I know that you yourself are less than $56$. Suppose that you have another friend who is also older than you, let's say her age is $z$, and suppose I know that she is more than $56$ years old. Then I have $x < z$ and $z > 56$, but these two facts together don't help me at all with estimating your age, $x$: You might be $10$, $21$, $75$, $100$, I just don't know. The first pair of inequalities work together, but the second pair don't.

Comment: Firstly, my apologies for the late reply, it's taken me a while to read through your answer enough times to understand it. There's an immense amount of work here, and I can't express my gratitude enough to you for doing it, which is why I hate all the more to have to say that I don't think my original goal is satisfied - I don't blame you for this at all, and will still award this answer with the full bounty that it deserves for being as enlightening as it is. Reading through your answer has made me realise that rather than the probability of no collisions at all, what I'm looking for...

Comment: ...is the formula that will allow me to determine what percentage of numbers in keyspace $n$ will turn out to be duplicates/collisions (without actually running any trials in code). So for example, where my keyspace is 100,000 (for a randomly-generated 5 digit number between 00000 to 99999), what percentage of those 100,000 numbers are likely to be collisions/duplicates? I would be able to use this formula to generate a table that lists keyspace sizes along with their respective percentages of collisions, and be able to use that table to look for the smallest keyspace that has an acceptable...

Comment: ...enough (to me) likelihood of collisions. Because my script incorporates logic that checks for duplicates, one or a few duplicates isn't an issue for me, and it's overkill to prevent every single one - what I'm trying to detect with the above formula is the amount of duplicates generated within my chosen keyspace being too high such that my script will be re-generating numbers more often than not, and therefore have its performance seriously impacted.

Comment: I see now that this probably isn't the birthday problem and that I was misled in thinking so in the answer to my question [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/233678/120534). If what I'm asking for is possible with a change to your current formulae, feel free to make the edit and I will award additional bounty to this answer accordingly. If it is possible but is a separate question, let me know and I will ask it separately, and of course award a bounty for both questions.

Comment: @Prometheus, you're welcome - it's no problem ! I appreciate your politeness and humility, if I may say so. It's possible that the earlier part of my answer, about the expected number of collisions, $E(Y-m)$, might be close to what you want. I understand that you want a proportion, rather than a number, but can you elaborate on why you want it to be a proportion of $n$, the size of your keyspace ? As I understand, you won't generate 100,000 invoice numbers, instead you will generate 3,500 (say). Is what you want, perhaps, the proportion of random invoice numbers generated that...

Comment: ...turned out to be collisions ? For example, your key space has size 1,000,000, and you need 3,500 distinct invoice numbers. You generate random numbers, discarding duplications (collisions) until you have 3,500 distinct ones. It turns out that you generated 3,511 numbers (so you must have had 11 collisions). So the proportion of collisions to numbers generated is 11/3,511 which is roughly 0.3% ? If so, then this proportion depends on 3 things: $n$, the size of your keyspace, $m$ the number of invoice numbers required, and also, on the luck you had during that...

Comment: ...particular run of your random code. If you want an answer that depend only on $n$ and $m$, then I think you have to compute some "statistic" of that random proportion of collisions, for example, it's average (i.e. "mean" a.k.a. "expected value"). When you write that "it's overkill to prevent every single [collision]", do you mean that it's ok if eventually some invoice numbers are actually used more than once ? In "real life" I envisage problems arising from this...

Comment: .... Or do you mean that you will insist on having a set of invoice numbers with absolutely *no* duplicates (sounds sensible to me) and that you don't mind if your duplicate-deleting routine is invoked a few times (but you don't want it to be activated *too* often) ?

Comment: In the following (very simple) example, what is the probability, or proportion that you would like to know ? My keyspace has size $n=10$. I require $m=6$ distinct invoice numbers. The program generates the following sequence of numbers: 3, 7, 9, 7 (collision), 4, 3 (collision), 3 (collision), 9 (collision), 2, 2 (collision), 3 (collision), 8 (stop, because we now have 6 distinct numbers). The invoice numbers are 3, 7, 9, 4, 2, 8.

Comment: `It turns out that you generated 3,511 numbers (so you must have had 11 collisions). So the proportion of collisions to numbers generated is 11/3,511 which is roughly 0.3% ?` Yes, this is what I'm after. The reason I wanted to use the whole keyspace instead of something smaller like 3,500 is simply because I want to have the freedom of being able to use the whole keyspace, in the case that even if I run this business for decades, I'll a) never run out of numbers, and b) always be able to calculate collisions, although even something smaller like a half or quarter of the keyspace might be fine.

Comment: `Or do you mean that you will insist on having a set of invoice numbers with absolutely no duplicates (sounds sensible to me) and that you don't mind if your duplicate-deleting routine is invoked a few times (but you don't want it to be activated too often) ?` Yes, exactly this. In your example, the number I would be after is 50% - the proportion of $m$ that were collisions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110025/discussion-between-simon-and-prometheus).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already used $N$ out of $10^5$ invoice numbers then the probability the next attempt collides with one of those may be $\frac{N}{10^5}$.

If you keep trying until you fail to collide, then this is a geometric distribution and the expected number of attempts needed would be $\frac{10^5}{10^5-N}$, and the expected total number of collisions is one less, i.e.  $\frac{N}{10^5-N}$

If you add these up for $N=0$ to $N=99999$ (after which you must stop as there would be no free invoice numbers) then you would expect to need $10^5H_{10^5} \approx 1209015$ attempts (related to harmonic numbers) and see about $1109015$ collisions

Comment: I'm really sorry for the work you've done here, but I'm after the probability of collision rather than the number of collisions, and it would suffice to simply know what the initial probability is rather than what it is after the generation of every new number.

Comment: @Prometheus, in your question, you wrote "I need to figure out how often I can expect a given keyspace to generate collisions". The number of collisions is a random variable, and there is a technical meaning to "the expected value of a random variable". It is in fact a weighted average of the possible numbers of collisions, the weights being the probabilities. Is it that your code will run and run, fixing collisions each time they arise, until it has generated some chosen number of distinct invoice numbers, and that you want to know "on average" how many collisions will have had to have been..

Comment: ..dealt with, by the time the chosen number of distinct invoice numbers has been generated ? Like you have 3,500 customers, so you ask your code to generate 3,500 invoice numbers, each one between 0 and 999,999 ? It runs for a few seconds, generating them one by one, fixing collisions as it goes, and terminates as soon as it has made 3,500 distinct numbers ?

Comment: It sounds to me as if that IS what you want, and moreover, you want a formula in terms of m, the number customers (say 3,500) and n, the number of possible invoice numbers (say 1,000,000), that tells you the *expected* number of collisions dealt with, during a one-time generation of 3,500 distinct, random invoice numbers. Then for example, given a certain number of customers, you will be able to find out what n should be, so that the expected number of collisions is below a certain tolerance of your choosing...

Comment: ...if all of that is a correct description of what you want, then you need to appreciate that the actual number of collisions is a random variable, X. If you are lucky, X could be zero. If you are very unlucky, X could be infinity ! That is, your code could run forever, by sheer bad luck never managing to make 3,500 distinct invoice numbers. Imagine a bar chart showing the probability of each possible value of X, from 0 to infinity (ok, let's stop at some large number, not infinity !) It's going to have a hump somewhere "in the middle"...

Comment: ... There are several things you might want to know about this bar chart: A formula telling you the height of every bar (i.e. the probability that X=k, for every value of k). The value of k with the highest bar (if indeed there is a unique such k) - this is called the "mode". The bar such that the total areas of the bars on the left is the same as the total area of the bars on the right (the "median"). Or you might want to know the value of k representing the left-right position of the "centre of mass" of all the bars (the "expected value" or "mean")...

Comment: ... You might also want a measure of how "spread out" the bars are. Is it that there a very tall few bars, and the ones on either side are very short ? Or is the hump very low and wide ? One such measure of spread is called "the variance". For many practical purposes, people want to know just the mean, i.e., the expected value of the random variable. Have a think and let us know whether or not the above model is what you intend, and if so, whether any of those measurements I just described is what you are looking for.